# D3 grouping bars

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I'm trying to figure out a way to group 2 bars and then leave some spacing between them. Is there a way to do this in D3? The example I'm following is this http://codepen.io/mbostock/pen/Jaemg.

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);

d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("div")
    .style("width", function(d) { return x(d) + "px"; })
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by spacing? Can you provide a screenshot of desired effect?

Comment: Do you mean "bar 4, bar 8, space, bar 15, bar 16, space, bar 23, bar 42"?

Comment: Yh, I mean  "bar 4, bar 8, space, bar 15, bar 16, space, bar 23, bar 42".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the result: https://jsfiddle.net/umeqw2f8/3/

I've changed your style function a bit to achieve this:

```
.style("width", function(d,i) { 
  if(i % 2 == 0 && i != 0){
    d3.select(this).style("margin-top", 5+"px")
  }else if(i == 0){}

  return x(d) + "px"; })
```

You can change the modulo factor for different sizes of grouping. For example for group of number 3: `if(i % 3 == 0 && i != 0){`

Comment: I bet 10RPs that this is not what the OP meant, although I really liked your answer!

Comment: @GerardoFurtado Haha, well the question is a little vague as you would appreciate. So I made the first answer that came to my mind and thought that we can move forward with OPs comments.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Sorry about the vague question. What i meant is  "bar 4, bar 8, space, bar 15, bar 16, space, bar 23, bar 42".

Comment: @user3837019 I updated my answer accordingly. If you want to change the grouping just change the modulo factor. i.e for 3 bars if(i % 3 == 0 && i != 0)

Answer (score 2):

The Idea is to group the bars in DIV and seperate the group div's with some margin or padding.

```
var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var gData=[];
for(var i=0;i<data.length/2;i++){
  gData[i]={
    "before":data[i*2],
    "after":data[i*2+1]
  };
}
console.log(gData);
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data)])
    .range([0, 420]);

myBarsEnter=d3.select(".chart")
  .selectAll("div.bars")
    .data(gData).enter().append('div').attr('class','bargroup');
  myBarsEnter.append('div')
            .style("width", function(d) { return x(d.before) + "px"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.before; });
myBarsEnter.append('div')
            .style("width", function(d) { return x(d.after) + "px"; })
            .text(function(d) { return d.after; });
```

And updated CSS is

```
.chart .bargroup{
margin-bottom:10px;
}
.chart .bargroup div {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  background-color: steelblue;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 1px;
  color: white;
}
```

You can find Updated code on below link.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqJpzK

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Mind telling me how you're changing the amount of bars to group. For example say if i wish to group 3 bars or even 4.

Comment: SAM83045 created an array with 3 objects, each one with two key/value pairs. If you want to group 3 bars with your data, for instante, you can create an array with two objects, each one with 3 pairs key/value. Btw, please accept his answer.

Comment: @user3837019 : It's better to group our data before sending it to D3 and based on that data you can easily draw bars as much you want. I have modified your data into groups first as  [{"before":4,"after":8},{"before":15,"after":16},{"before":23,"after":42}] and then passed them for printing.